# How to parallelly run several crawlers by Crawlee? I get some errors

Tags: node.js, crawlee

I use [Crawlee](https://crawlee.dev/) in my project.

I want run **2 crawler parallelly** by this way:

```
await Promise.all([
  crawler1.run(),
  crawler2.run(),
]);
```

But I get this error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\project-crawler\storage\request_queues\default\iMCIUbrRaOsVice.json']
```

[image]

if I comment one of the crawlers it works without any errors:

```
await Promise.all([
  crawler1.run(),
  // crawler2.run(),
]);
```